# Knockout checkbox binding, with autoupdate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to when a person changes the state of previously bound checkbox, I want to update the server with the new value.
So here is what I have:

JSCRIPT

```
function JobViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var baseUri = '/Api/Pedidos/';

        self.TotalItems = ko.observable(@Model.TotalItems);
        self.AbreviaNome = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaNome.ToString().ToLower());
        self.AbreviaFantasia = ko.observable(@Model.AbreviaFantasia.ToString().ToLower());

        self.update = function () {
            alert('Boom');
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: baseUri,
                data: self.Job,
                datatype: "json",
                contenttype: "application/json"
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    //handleSuccessFunctionHERE(data);
                    alert('Magic');
                })
                .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert("fail");
                });
        };
    }

    function JobDetailsViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var baseUri = '/Api/Pedidos/';
        self.Job = new JobViewModel();

    }
```

HTML

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active:Job.AbreviaNome }">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: AbreviaNome , onchange: Job.update" name="type" id="AbreviaNome "> Nome</input>
</label>
```

This never triggers the update function. I also have tried :

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="css: {active:Job.AbreviaNome }">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: AbreviaNome , click: Job.update" name="type" id="AbreviaNome "> Nome</input>
</label>
```

And this within the JobViewModel:

```
this.AbreviaNome.subscribe(function (newValue) {                
      alert('test');
}, this);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, below is the binding:

```
 <label class="btn btn-primary " data-bind="css: {active:Job.AbreviaNome}">
     <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Job.AbreviaNome, event: {change: Job.update}" name="type" id="AbreviaNome">Nome/Razão</input>
 </label>
```

Not sure this was the best way but it works.

Comment: Avoid using the change event binding. You don't need it. You should handle changes the knockout way - use subscribe.

Comment: I am trying that but its not working, it does not fail, or anything. When I put a breakpoint on the subscribe method, it never fires

Answer (score 0):

You should use `subscribe` for this and not the `onchange` handler. You mentioned you tried it, but you subscribed to AbreviaNome instead of AbreviaLogradouro.

Comment: Fixed the sample since you referred the error on the field that I was binding.